# zoom property, for regular video instance?

Tags: actionscript-3

I notice that there is a zoom property on the new StageVideo class...is there something similar for the regular video object in Actionscript 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a zoom property the Video class. Zooming for the Video object would have to be a combination of DisplayObject scale and maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: I tried to set the my properties so that my video would "zoom out", i.e. video.scaleX = video.scaleY = .5, but this just makes my video smaller - is there a way to make it show more in the frame?

Comment: `1` is 100% `.5` is 50% so to scale up you must is a value higher that `1`.

Comment: 2 is 200%, but this "zooms in" my video image...is there a way to "zoom out" the image??